# php coding function and dropdown declaration

Tags: php

so my problem is the coding is not inserted into database and the date picker also problem.

html

```
    <?php
            include('connection.php');
            include('book.php');
        ?>

   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="datetimepicker.js">
   </script>   
   </header> 

    <!-- Main content -->

    <section class="row">
      <div class="grid">

            <label>
              Hour of Services
              <select name="quantity">
                <option value="1" selected>1 hour</option>
                <option value="2">1.5 hour</option>
                <option value="3">2 hour</option>
                <option value="4">2.5 hour</option>
                <option value="5">3 hour</option>
              </select>
              <span id="hourError" class="error"><?php echo $hourError; ?>  </span>
            </label>

           <label>
            Choose Date
            <input type="Text" id="demo1" maxlength="25" size="25"><a href="javascript:NewCal('demo1','ddmmmyyyy',true,24)"><img src="cal.jpg" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Pick a date"></a>
            <span class="descriptions">pick a date..</span>
             <span id="dateError" class="error2"><?php echo $dateError; ?></span>
</label>
<br>


            <label>
              Notes
     <textarea id="note" onblur="checknote()" name="note"><?php echo $note; ?></textarea>
                                <span id="noteError" class="error2"><?php echo $noteError; ?></span>

            <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="submit" value="booking">
          </fieldset>
        </form>

      </div>
      </section>

      </body>
      </html>
```

my php , something is wrong with my declaration?

Define variables

```
    $username = "";
    $hour = "";
    $date = "";
    $note = "";
```

Define error variables

```
    $usernameError = "";
    $hourError = "";
    $dateError = "";
    $noteError = "";
```

When the submit button is press do this

```
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $username = trim($_POST['username']);
        $hour = trim($_POST['hour']);
        $date = trim($_POST['date']);
        $note = trim($_POST['note']);
```

my dropdown seems like not correct

```
        function checkhour($hour){
            global $hourError;
                 if ($hour === "pleaseselect") {
                $hourError = "Please choose an option from the drop down list";
                return false;
            }
            $hourError = "hour select!";
            return true;
        }
```

function that to check all

```
 function checkAll($username, $hour, $date, $note){
     if (checkusername($username) & checkhour($hour) & checknote($note)) {
                    if(empty($errors)){
    $query = "INSERT INTO book (username,hour,date,note) VALUES ('$username','$hour',,'$date''$note')";
    $result = mysql_query ($query);
    if ($result)
        echo "<script language='javascript'>alert ('booked success!'); </script>";

    }
    checkAll($username, $hour, $date, $note);

    }
?>
```

i don't know , its just the date , and dropdown doesn't working. little help please

Comment: A form requires a `form` element in HTML.

Comment: No form element. Unclosed divs. Please, organize your code before posting. Doing so is important for you and for those intending to help you, 'cause then they don't need to spend time organizing things to you.

Answer (score 1):

1. first of all wrap all your form elements with a form tag and set correct action, method parameter.
2. change select element name attribute as "hour"

   ```
   <select name="hour">
   ```
3. add name attribute to date input field

   ```
   <input type="text" id="demo1" maxlength="25" size="25" name="date">
   ```
4. add input field for username paraments

   ```
   <input type="text" name="username">
   ```